# Move back with git by moving a branch pointer

Tags: git

Let's consider this situation:

```
                  v devel
o--x--o--o--o--o--o
                \ 
                 o--o
                    ^ feature
```

I would like to move the `devel` branch to `x` and replace it with a new name:

```
   v devel        v fork
o--o--o--o--o--o--o
                \ 
                 o--o
                    ^ feature
```

From other questions on SO, I found that `git update-ref` or `git rebase` might help. However the solution I found is:

```
git branch -m devel fork
git checkout -b devel x   # where x is the commit number `x`
```

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: If there's no particular need for the checkout `git checkout -b` does you can just `git branch devel x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the easiest way to do it (in my opinion).

And, as long as you don't modify the existing commits, it doesn't have undesired side-effects if you push your changes to a remote repository (presumably used by other people too).

However, don't commit anything on the new location of `devel`. If you do it and you push your changes then you'll confuse your coworkers.

Let's say you commit on the new location of branch `devel` (this is why you want to move it, right?) and push your changes. Your repo (and the origin too) looks like this:

```
                  v fork
o--o--o--o--o--o--o
    \           \ 
     o           o--o
     ^ devel        ^ feature
```

But your co-workers have the original tree (where `devel` is at `fork` and `fork` doesn't exist). When they try to `pull` git will attempt to merge your `devel` into `fork` (their `devel`). Because now neither of the two branches is an ancestor of the other one, `fast-forward` is not possible and merging them requires the creation of a new commit. And that might not be what you (and they) want.

All in all, moving a branch backwards is generally a bad idea. You have been warned!

Comment: Pushing `devel` backwards would absolutely have side-effects in a remote repo

Comment: Yes, it has side-effects but they are not difficult to manage. The co-workers that pulled the branch `devel` yesterday will discover today that they are 5 commits ahead of the `origin` even if they didn't change anything. The real trouble starts when you push rebased versions of commits that already exists on the remote repository. Or if you move `devel` outside the path reachable from `fork` (its location known on the remote repo).